# TypeScript Data Types casting

Tags: angular, typescript, type-conversion

I am new in TypeScript/Angular JS 2. I have one function written in C# that I need to convert in TypeScript. Below is the function-

```
public static MyModel GetDetails(IDictionary<string, object> Obj) {

  MyModel dlModel = new MyModel();
  if (Obj.ContainsKey("action"))

    dlModel.action = ((IEnumerable<object>)Obj["action"]).Cast<string>().ToList();
  if (Obj.ContainsKey("parameters")) {

    List<object> pr = ((IEnumerable<object>)Obj["parameters"]).Cast<object>().ToList();
    foreach (object obj in pr) {
      IDictionary<string, object> kValue = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;

      dlModel.parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kValue["Key"].ToString(), kValue["Value"].ToString()));


    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to use IDictionary and IEnumerable in TypeScript. So can anyone help me out in TypeScript data types.

Comment: Dictionary would be an indexable object and enumerable an array.

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me. I don't know how I could help apart from writing a possible implementation in TypeScript. What are your problems with type casting and what are your problems with `IDictionary` and `IEnumerable`? Basically you can use `Map` or the special type `any` for `IDictionary` and `Iterable` for `IEnumerable` in TypeScript. Values can be cast with the keywourd `as`.

Comment: @JojOatXGME there is no type casting in typescript, only type assertion. the key word as just tells the compiler what the type of a variable is (it doesn't do anything at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

> So can anyone help me out in TypeScript data types.

Best to use `{[key: string]: SomeObject}` where `SomeObject` is the *value* for a given *string key*.

## More

Some docs on index signatures : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Comment: #basarat, it's not clear that, how I can convert "IEnumerable<object>" in typescript.